# Vim: Redefining :h and :help to Split Vertically

Tags: vim, remap

I would like to redefine the `:h` and `:help` commands, so that they split the screen vertically by default. The following solutions are undesirable for two reasons.

```
cnoremap h vert help
cabbrev h vert help
```

1. I only want the substitution to occur for `:*` commands. Unfortunately, the substitution also occurs when I type `/h`. I scanned through the documentation on maps, but I could not find a command that will only remap `:*` commands and not `/*` commands.
2. I only want the substitution to occur when the command starts with `:h`. If I type `:ah`, the command is expanded to `:avert help`. This behavior may be desirable when I pipe commands together, but I don't want it here.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I strongly advise you to give Kent's answer a shot as it's very simple.  If you really want to redefine the command you can limit this redefinition to only `:` commands (see `:h getcmdtype()`).  See https://github.com/rson/vimscript-snippets/blob/master/lowercase_commands.vim for an example of how to use this.

Comment: @RandyMorris I had actually come across an article where I just read about `getcmdtype()`, but Kent's answer is a lot cleaner. Unfortunately, I have a funny issue which I commented about below Kent's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746) plugin for that, but you can also solve this with a clever mapping:

```
:cnoreabbrev <expr> h getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == "h" ? "vert h" : "h"
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works well. Personally, I would replace `vert` with `vert belowright`, as this opens the help window in the right panel.

Comment: In response to my previous comment: actually, no I would not recommend replacing `vert` with `vert belowright`. Setting `set splitright` is a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to redefine the :h and :help commands, so that they split
>   the screen vertically by default.

In my vimrc, I have:

```
"====================
"Help in vertical split (right)
"====================
autocmd FileType help wincmd L
```

if you want the help show in left vertical split, use `H` instead of `L`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I came across a strange issue, however. The window split vertically the first time I tried, but horizontally the second time. I'm going to try again after I move my `.vimrc`, in case any of my plugins may be interfering.

Comment: After using manual binary search on my `.vimrc` file, I isolated the line in my `.vimrc` causing the problem: `set hidden`.

Comment: @void-pointer from your comment I cannot see the problem. that line I wrote in vimrc long time ago, didn't have your problem...

Answer (score 1):

A very lo-tech solution:

```
nnoremap <leader>h :vert help <-- there's a <space> here
```